# converting a rect from one sytem to another

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage, geometry, cgrect

I need to convert a CGRect from one UIImage to another resized UIImage.

For instance if Image A (original) size = 100,100 and the rect is {50,50,50,50}

in A' (destination) size = {50,50} need to convert rect' (destination rect) to {25,25,25,25}

Wondering if there is a function that can do it for me? For now just transforming coordinate system, but in future might have rotated rects, and it could involve some complicated trigonometry - would like to save that.

Edit:
Adding an image to explain the problem
[image: Problem Definition]

Answer (score 1):

Sure there are some helpers ready to use.

CGAffineTransform is the one you are looking for for example:

```
CGAffineTransform transform1 = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(-50, -50);
CGAffineTransform transform2 = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI/2);
CGRect myRect = CGRectMake(100,100,100,100);
CGRect transformedRect = CGRectApplyAffineTransform(myRect, transform1);
```

Check CGAffineTransform.h for full list.

Comment: is the translation the destination rect in pixels (diff in rect i mean)

Comment: it's in x,y coordinates :) which is not really "pixel". Whatever units you are using - they will remain the same.

Comment: Just to be clear, the translation is the offset in pixels (x,y) meaning if my original rect is {50,50,200,200} in the new system where the containing rect was reduced by {a,b} pixels the original rect in that system would be, CGAffineTransform transform1 = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(-a, -b); CGRect transformedRect = CGRectApplyAffineTransform(myRect, transform1);

Comment: I think you are more looking for CGAffineTransformMakeScale(xScale, yScale). Where scales are correspoding to A'x / Ax and A'y / Ay. If I understood properly form your example what are you trying to do :)

Comment: I'll link an image. I think its the easiest

Comment: Edited the question and added an image